# How to show SQL query result in a Textbox?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have the following code:

```
dbConnection cn = new dbConnection();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
protected void dropdown_student_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string StudentGUID = dropdown_student.SelectedValue;
    cn.con.Open();
    cn.cmd.Connection = cn.con;
    cn.cmd.CommandText = "select SUM(Marks) AS 'Total' from Marksheet where StudentGUID = " + StudentGUID + " ";
    dr = cn.cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {            
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            textbox_total.Text = dr["Total"].ToString();
        }
        cn.con.Close();
    }
}
```

I want to show the total marks value in the textbox but it does not work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: you're getting any error or what is the output getting in dr["Total"]?

Comment: what value you are getting in  "textbox_total.Text" ?

Comment: @ Aravind Sivam error is like that---- Incorrect syntax near 'DB73801'. and the line is ---- dr = cn.cmd.ExecuteReader();

Comment: Only single quotes are missing in your query. see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// define your query upfront - using a PARAMETER!
string query = "SELECT SUM(Marks) FROM dbo.Marksheet WHERE StudentGUID = @StudentID;";

// put the SqlConnection and SqlCommand into using blocks    
using (dbConnection cn = new dbConnection())
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
{
    // define the parameter value
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value =  dropdown_student.SelectedValue;

    cn.Open();

    // use ExecuteScalar if you fetch one row, one column exactly
    object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    cn.Close();

    if(result != null)
    {
        int value = (int)result;
        textbox_total.Text = value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: @SimpleMan: what single quotes? Where? When using **parameters** in a SQL query (as you **always** should), there's no need for single quotes ....

Answer (score 0):

You SQL query is wrong. Try like below:

```
string query = string.Format("SELECT SUM(Marks) FROM dbo.Marksheet WHERE StudentGUID = '{0}';", StudentID);
```

Always try to follow this kind of standard practice and you will never fail.

Comment: Standard practice would be using `Parameterized` query, check @ marc_s answer

Comment: You are right. But I was talking about string concatenation only.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting single Quote around the GUID variable in SQL query.

```
cn.cmd.CommandText = "select SUM(Marks) AS 'Total' from Marksheet where StudentGUID = '" + StudentGUID + " '";
```